Singular behavior of zeros of incomplete zeta function
I've been looking at the zeros of the incomplete zeta function
$\zeta_{lower}(s, z)$ recently.
$$
\zeta_{\mathrm{lower}}(s,z)=-\frac{{\Gamma(1-s)}}{2\pi i}\int_{z}^{\infty}\frac{{(-t)^{s-1}}}{e^{t}-1}dt
$$
The subscript "lower" indicates that the contour of integration passes below
the branch cut on the positive real axis.
By zeros, I mean I mean the zeros in $z$, for fixed $s$.
I find that this function can have
an infinite number of complex zeros $z_k$, each of which is a function of the parameter $s$. The zeros (for fixed $s$) live on a smooth curve and have an accumulation point at the origin.
Let $s_0$ be any zero of the (original, complete) Riemann zeta function.  A remarkable
thing happens when $s$ is near $s_0$.  The kth zero, $z_k(s)$ depends
logarithmically on $(s_0-s)$.
$$
\log(z_k(s)) \approx \frac{1}{s-1} \log(s_0-s) + C_k(s_0)
$$
Assuming $|\operatorname{Im}(s)| >> |\operatorname{Re}(s)|$, the entire set $z_k$ rotate about the origin as
$s \rightarrow s_0$.  Imagine a (slightly bent) barn door rotating about its hinge.
For added fun, if you move $s$ around $s_0$ and return to the original point, $z_k$ will become $z_{k+1}$ or $z_{k-1}$ depending on the sense of the rotation in $s$.
I've verified these prediction numerically down to a distance of $10^{-20}$ between $s$ and $s_0$.
So my question is whether anyone has seen this before, for the zeta
function or for other incomplete functions.

You displayed equation is not precise enough to say anything.  The left side depends on $k$, the right does not (or only implicitly $C=C_k$).  The right side depends on $s_0$, the left does not.  What happens if $s_0$ is replaced with another zeta zero $s_0^\prime$?  How can the left be $\approx$ both?

Fair catch.  $C_k$ does depend on $s_0$ and the relation is only valid in the $s$ neighborhood of $s_0$. I've edited the question to make that clear.
